# Strongly convexity of a nonlinear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I got the following nonlinear functional
$$J\left(u\right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}\left[H\left(\nabla u\right)\right]^2\;dx-\int_{\Omega}f\cdot u\;dx,\;\forall\;v\in X$$,
where $H$ is a Finsler norm, who is convex.

How to prove that this functional is strongly convex?

Comment: This functional is linear on constant functions, so not strongly convex without further assumptions. What is $X$? Is $H$ strongly convex?

Comment: $H$ is just a norm who is convex and homogeneous of degree 1, but not linear. I don't know if it is strongly convex. X is just a Hilbert space.